# Error:"The parameterized query expects the parameter @UserName which was not supplied"

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have an error when I'm running my application saying that the parameter @UserName is not supplied.I have tried different approaches like using the add method for the parameter and defining it and also I'm checking if there are null values in the DB but for nothing,I still get the same error.
This is my code where the error produces:
**LoginViewModel.cs**:

```
using LastAndFinalVersion.Helpers;
using LastAndFinalVersion.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;


namespace LastAndFinalVersion.ViewModel
 {
  class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private DelegateCommand loginCommand;
    private  Login _UserName;
    private  Login _pwd;
    private Login CurrentUser { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler OnPropertyChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Login UserName
    {
        get { return _UserName; }
        set
        {
            _UserName = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged("UserName");
        }


    }


public Login pwd
    {
        get { return _pwd; }
        set
        {
            if(_pwd!=value)
            {
                _pwd = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("pwd");
            }
        }
    }


public LoginViewModel():base()
{
    ButtonCommand = new DelegateCommand(SubmitButton);



}
public DelegateCommand ButtonCommand
{
    get { return loginCommand; }
    set
    {
        if (loginCommand != value)
            loginCommand = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonCommand");
    }
}

protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (OnPropertyChanged != null)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

    public void SubmitButton()
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\source\repos\VIAApp2Demo\VIAApp2Demo\DB\DatabaseStudents.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        try
        {
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                conn.Open();
            String query = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Login WHERE UserName=@UserName AND pwd=@pwd";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         SqlParameter Username=cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", _UserName);
            if(Username==null)
            {
                Username.Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            SqlParameter Pwd = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", _pwd);
            if(Pwd==null)
            {
                Pwd.Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            if (count > 0)

            {
                MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
                main.Show();
                main.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect!");
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
   }
  }
   }
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thank you!

@Mustafa This is the Login.cs model class:

```
 namespace LastAndFinalVersion.Model
{
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public partial class Login
{
public Nullable<int> SNTeacher { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
public int pwd { get; set; }

public virtual RegisterTeacher RegisterTeacher { get; set; }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Post the *relevant* code, don't dump the entire class. In any case, the error is clear. Somewhere in all this you are trying to execute a query but forgot to pass one of the parameters. Pass the parameter. If you debug the application you'll find where the error occured

Comment: Your SQL query is just one long string!? You've not appended your param details to it, but you also appear to be using parameters? Also, do not use dynamic SQL in your code.. this leaves you open to SQL injection.

Comment: Also post the *actual, full * exception, including the call stack. not a description of it. You can get it with `Exception.ToString().

Comment: @Wheels73 there's no dynamic sql in this form????? It's one parameterized query, that commits the cardinal sin of using `AddWithValue` to pass .... an object

Comment: cant help but wonder although you've added parameters _UserName is not a string its a class, and maybe thats where its going wrong.  what is "Login"

Comment: _UserName is object? have you tried to convert it to string?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I jut couldn't think of the right phrase! :)

Comment: Can you paste `Login` class' code?

Comment: @Panagiotis Thank you for you response.I have managed to do the error while I was waiting for your response.I have noticed that I have a problem elsewhere actualy,that is why I was keep changing the code,because although I have values in the database,I can't log in using the username and password because UserName and pwd have null values no matter what...Do you have any idea why this might happen although I have values in the DB?Sorry about the post and the way I did it but I don't have experience on this site.

Comment: @BugFinder Login was the model class for LoginViewModel

Comment: <pre>     using System;
                  using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    
         public partial class Login
        {
        public Nullable<int> SNTeacher { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public int pwd { get; set; }
    
        public virtual RegisterTeacher RegisterTeacher { get; set; }
    } <code>

Comment: So what sort of fields are username and pwd? do you not just want the string value from your login class

Comment: @BugFinder UserName is of type nvarchar and pwd is of type int.

Comment: So you have a login class, which holds the string and the int, but you're using separate instances to store the string in one and the int in the other.. so, you need to use _username.Username and _pwd..pwd as the values...

Comment: @BugFinder Got it!Thank you so much,I'll try it now!

Comment: @ElizaMaria did it work? should I put this in as an answer for you?

Comment: @BugFinder no it didn't work unfortunately.I tried to do it your way and it gives me the error"Object not set to an instance of an object" .But thank you for your patience and help! :(

Comment: then check what is in _username and _pwd cos it sounds like one of them was null

Comment: Actually both of them are null and I have no idea how to make it work because I have asked even my teachers and they said that the sintax is ok,but maybe the problem is far more complicated than expected.I'm not good at all in MVVM,I just started coding this app in WPF because it was recommended from one of my friends,plus I want to learn something else than winforms.I will see what I can do,and if i manage to find the solution,I will upload it here.

Comment: @BugFinder The two values are not null in the database but they are null when the program is running so I'm guessing somehow along the road I miss something...

Comment: aye, definately.. nothing in the code you posted shows that being populated.. so.. cant really help on that

Comment: I know,I inserted data manually in the table just to see if it works or not,I guess it doesn't.Thank you for your time :)!